# Floated Select not showing the select options with Chosen Jquery Plugin

Tags: jquery, css, css-float, jquery-chosen

I am trying to implement [Chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) for showing drop down options. Here is how I am trying it, but I am not able to get the options. Actually, they are getting available, but they get overflown in the outer div and I have to scroll the div. Here is the jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/HZUeF/.

```
<div id="searchFilters" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column" style="width:19%">
            <span class="filter-header">Select 1</span>
            <select id="select1" class="chosen-select" multiple>
              <option value="28">Option 1</option>
              <option value="90">Option 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column" style="width:16%">
            <span class="filter-header">Select 2</span>
            <select id="select2">
              <option value="28">Option 1</option>
              <option value="90">Option 2</option>
              <option value="95">Option 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
body {
    font:12px 'Verdana';
}

#searchFilters tr tr{
     padding-bottom: 1em;
}
#searchFilters {
    border:0px solid black;
}

#searchFilters .row {
    border:0px solid red;
    margin-top:10px;
    overflow:auto;
}

#searchFilters .column {
    border:0px solid blue;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:#0099CC;
}

#searchFilters .filter-header {
    border:0px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left:10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: black;
    margin:5px 0px 3px 0px;
}

#searchFilters .column select {
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
}
```

---

```
$(function() {
    $("#select1").chosen({});
    $("#select2").chosen({});   
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `overflow:none` for `#searchFilters .row`

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HZUeF/3/)**

Comment: Yours worked just fine. I added one more option as ````clear:left```` to make sure my ````.row```` always goes below the options selected in above row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#searchFilters .row {
    border:0px solid red;
    margin-top:10px;
    overflow:visible; //OR remove overflow property
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HZUeF/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
 overflow:auto
```

have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/HZUeF/1/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the CSS `overflow` property:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/UyTYf/1/)

**CSS**:

```
#searchFilters .row {
    border:0px solid red;
    margin-top:10px;
    /*overflow:auto;*/
}
```